# A list of all Sharepoint-specific tags & attributes for PageLayout/MP use?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, page-layout, html

I'm having trouble locating a url/document or a book, that describes extensively all the tags and attributes we can use within Page Layouts and Master Pages (2010) in order to change the way that HTML is rendered. For example: I know there's an attribute that changes the out of the box left navigation from Tables to Unordered lists.

I'm doing front-end development and I'd like to get as much control of my html (and css of course) as possible.

One other thing is for example removing tables from web part zones and web parts. Again, are there attributes that do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not attribute for changing the table-based rendering for Web Part Zones and Web Parts. The recommended strategy is the use of a Control Adapter. Here are a couple of blog posts with examples.

http://blog.mikehacker.net/2009/10/21/using-a-control-adapter-for-branding-part-2/
http://blog.mastykarz.nl/removing-web-parts-tables-sharepoint-2010/